# Docker Compose not updating content

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have some containers running with docker compose but I just can't find a way to properly update my containers without having to remove it and create it again. I have a Python app and I can successfully deploy code changes and those get applied, but if I add files like css, js or images those don't get to the container.

I have tried with this command, even though in the console it logs the messages as expected (rebuild it with no cache) I had no no success:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache web && docker-compose up -d
```

The only command that works for me is to remove it like this:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
```

And then build and deploy:

```
docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
    - redis
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/donare/static
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :8000 --limit-request-line 16384 donare.app:app

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

data:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  command: "true"

postgres:
  restart: always
  build: .
  dockerfile: dockerfile-postgres
  volumes_from:
    - data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"

redis:
  image: redis

celery:
  build: ./web
  command: celery worker --app=donare.tasks.tasks
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  links:
    - postgres
    - redis
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Docker Compose file shows that you have a named volume in the `web` container. Is `/usr/src/app/donare/static` where your css, js, and images are supposed to come from on your Docker host? If so, perhaps you meant to mount `/usr/src/app/donare/static` into your container, not create a volume with that name? Or, if the css, js, and images are built into your image, then you should probably just remove that named volume.

Assuming your css, js, and images are at the path `/usr/src/app/donare/static` in the container, then what's happening is that because you have a named volume there, the first time you run the `web` service, a volume is being created and initialized with the contents at that path. Every time you do your `build` and `up`, that same initial volume is being mounted at the path with your old files. When you `stop` and `rm`, the volume is implicitly being deleted too, causing it to be recreated and initialized with fresh files.